# Headline not showing above Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollmagic

I created my portfolio a few months ago and everything was working fine. After about half a year I reopened the code again and now it is not working correctly anymore.
I had text show up above a canvas with **scrollmagic.js** and watching it unfold in the inspector it still seems to work *(as in opacity is still changing)* but it is not becoming visible. I tried both in Safari and Chrome.

I will put the parts of code here, I think may be relevant for this error.

```
<section id="wrapper">
    <canvas class="canvasScreen intro">
      <h1 class="hideit hello"><span class="head1">Dream.</span><span class="head2">Create.</span></h1>
      
      <h1 class="showme">Hi, I'm XXX. <br/>
      Media & Interaction Design Student. <br/>
      I want to dream new interesting ideas and create fascinating tech.
      </h1>
      <div class="hideit container">
        <div class="chevron"></div>
        <div class="chevron"></div>
        <div class="chevron"></div>
        </div>
      </canvas>
    </section>
```

I added the Wrapper in hopes of fixing it but then I would not be here :)
I also tried adding the z-index to no avail.

```
.canvasScreen{
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100vh !important;
  width: 100vw !important;
}


.hello{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 10vw;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.showme{
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#wrapper{
  min-height: 350vh;

}
```

And if it is necessary (as it seems to work):

```
//TEXTANIMATION
const textAnim = TweenMax.fromTo(text, 3, {opacity: 1}, {opacity: 0});

const scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: wrapper,
    triggerHook: 0,
    duration: 800,
})
.setTween(textAnim)
.addTo(controller)
```

I sadly get no Error codes.
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: TweenMax is not defined

Comment: @Oste Wouldn't I get an Errorcode for that? And what should I add to define it? I just looked into the scrollmagic examples and there it seems to be the same as I have here.
Also I can see the effect of it working in the Inspect Panel, as the opacity of textAnim changes along with me scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the Text out of the Canvas in HTML. Now it works like before.

```
<section id="wrapper">
    <canvas class="canvasScreen intro">
      </canvas>
      <h1 class="hideit hello"><span class="head1">Dream.</span><span class="head2">Create.</span></h1>
      
      <h1 class="showme">Hi, I'm XXX. <br/>
      Media & Interaction Design Student. <br/>
      I want to dream new interesting ideas and create fascinating tech.
      </h1>
      <div class="hideit container">
        <div class="chevron"></div>
        <div class="chevron"></div>
        <div class="chevron"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Still cannot really explain why it worked before but at least it does again. Hope it helps someone else in the future :)